# RSpec allow persisting between contexts

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a Ruby (`3.1.0p0 (2021-12-25 revision fb4df44d16) [x86_64-linux]`) module functioning as a singleton object that acts as an interface between my broader application and a file system json object that persists data.

I am part of the way through writing specs to test the behavior of the singleton's sole public method, and am noticing odd behavior surrounding rspec's (`3.12`) `allow`.

I am trying to test what the singleton does in the context of a specific state (eg the argument passed to it does not have a specific attribute) which might occur halfway through the method.

I am stubbing out all downstream behaviors of the singleton that might raise errors or prompt calls to `gets` to isolate the behavior in the context of the state and have a successful test. This means stubbing `File#read` with a given argument.

My problem is that I have two equally valid states to test and the allowance of File to have the stubbed behavior is persisting once the context in which is declared ends.

At this point, looking at the code directly is probably more useful.

my singleton:

```
# production.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'json'

module AtomicCards
  module Mana
    # Defines the colors of mana for which a land face can tap
    module Production
      extend self

      LOCAL_DATA_PATH = 'lib/mtg_json/data'
      LOCAL_FILE_NAME = 'mana_production'
      FileUtils.mkpath(LOCAL_DATA_PATH)

      def from(card_face)
        return unless card_face['types'].include?('Land')

        face_name = card_face['faceName'] || card_face['name']
        raise "no face_name on #{card_face}" unless face_name

        cache_user_provided_production(face_name, card_face['type'], card_face['text']) unless cache[face_name]

        cache[face_name]
      end

      private

      def cache
        @cache ||= local_file_available? ? local_data : {}
      end

      def complete_local_path = "#{LOCAL_DATA_PATH}/#{LOCAL_FILE_NAME}.json"
      def local_file_available? = File.size?(complete_local_path)
      def local_data = JSON.parse(File.read(complete_local_path))

      def cache_user_provided_production(face_name, ...)
        # system('clear')
        validated_input = validated_user_input(face_name, ...)

        cache.merge!({ face_name => %w[W U B R G C] & validated_input.chars }) && save!
        # system('clear')
      end

      def validated_user_input(...)
        prompt_user(...)

        case input = gets.chomp.upcase!
        when 'NIL' then input.clear
        when /^[WUBRGC]*$/ then input
        else retry_user_input(...)
        end
      end

      def prompt_user(face_name, type_line, text_box)
        puts "Please enter mana production string (wubrgc) or 'nil' for #{face_name}:"
        puts
        puts type_line
        puts text_box
      end

      def retry_user_input(...)
        system('clear')
        puts 'Invalid input detected. Try again.'
        validated_user_input(...)
      end

      def save!
        File.binwrite(CACHE_FILE_PATH, JSON.pretty_generate(cache.sort.to_h))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

my spec:

```
# production_spec.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'
require '/app/lib/mtg_json/atomic_cards/mana/production'

Production = AtomicCards::Mana::Production

RSpec.describe Production do
  subject { Production }
  let(:mocked_non_land) { { 'types' => %w[Planeswalker] } }
  let(:mocked_nameless_land_face) { { 'types' => %w[Land] } }
  let(:mocked_single_face_land) { { 'name' => 'Fake Single-Faced Land', 'types' => %w[Land] } }
  let(:mocked_dual_face_land) { { 'faceName' => 'Fake Dual-Faced Land', 'types' => %w[Land] } }
  let(:mocked_complete_cache) { { 'Fake Single-Faced Land' => [], 'Fake Dual-Faced Land' => [] }.to_json }

  before(:each) do
    allow(File).to receive(:read).and_call_original
    allow(File).to receive(:size?).and_return(false)
  end

  describe '.from' do
    context 'when passed a non-land card face' do
      specify { expect(subject.from(mocked_non_land)).to be_nil }
    end

    context 'when passed a card face without a name-like attribute' do
      specify { expect { subject.from(mocked_nameless_land_face) }.to raise_error(RuntimeError) }
    end

    context 'when passed a card face with a name attribute' do
      specify do
        allow(File).to receive(:size?).and_return(true)
        allow(File).to receive(:read).and_return(mocked_complete_cache)
        expect { subject.from(mocked_single_face_land) }.not_to raise_error
      end
    end

    context 'when passed a card face with a faceName attribute' do
      specify do
        # allow(File).to receive(:size?).and_return(true)
        # allow(File).to receive(:read).and_return(mocked_complete_cache)
        expect { subject.from(mocked_dual_face_land) }.not_to raise_error
      end
    end

    context 'when a local cache file exists' do
    end

    context 'when no local cache file exists' do
    end

    context 'when the face name does not appear in the cache' do
    end

    context 'when the face name appears in the cache' do
    end
  end
end
```

Running the spec above passes all four tests, even though `when passed a card face with a faceName attribute` ought to fail, since `File` should not exhibit stubbed behavior here.

Indeed, if the two `allow` lines from `when passed a card face with a name attribute` (test 3) are commented out, the rspec run completes with failures as expected.

I have tried making the rspec as copied above fail by wrapping test 3's `allow` lines in a before block, calling a daisychained `.with(filename)` method, among other things to no avail.

Is there something I am not understanding about the scoping rules of RSpec's `allow` method?

Comment: It's likely your `cache` - you don't properly reset the state of your singleton between tests. Try swapping tests nr. 3 and 4 and running rspec with `--order defined` - I'd expect the 4th one (that becomes 3rd after the swap) would fail.

Comment: I forgot to include that in the "things I've tried" section. I indeed did try reversing the order and what you predict was was happened. Clearly order dependent.

Comment: Ahhh,, when you say its my `cache`, you mean its the fact that I memoized the result of finding it on my filesystem! That is almost certainly the correct answer. Lemme mess around a bit

Answer (score 1):

[Konstantin Strukov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8008340/konstantin-strukov) nailed the issue on its head: I am memoizing the `@cache` instance variable on my singleton.

As this value persists for the duration of the Ruby process, the two solutions are:

1. abandon the memoization, finding a different coding strategy for my singleton's behavior
2. add `Production.remove_instance_variable(:@cache) if Production.instance_variable_defined?(:@cache)` to an appropriately-placed `before(:each)` block to reset the value between expectations/contexts

I plan on having this singleton's `.from` methods run several thousand times during my `db:seed` procedure, necessitating solution 2) above.

Many thanks, Konstantin!